# How to fix gtk dependencies?

Tags: gtk3, fontconfig

I installed `GTK+ 3.22`, but by doing so I managed to break my system completely for a while. I had to resort to recovery mode and to deleting all libraries related to `GTK` and then run `apt-get purge libgtk+3.0 && apt-get install libgtk+3.0`.

After that I managed to enter **lightdm** and log in, but I had absolutely no icons. All GTK applications had no icons and were generating lots of warnings. I figured it is a gdk-pixbuff problem since the errors were all saying something about that library, so I purged and installed `libgdk-pixbuf2.0`. This fixed the icons issue, but still some of my apps give me warnings about missing icons.

Now I have font problems, in the sense that the fonts look horrible and I cannot launch any `Cocos2d-x` application due to the fact that the library relies on GTK. The error says that it cannot find the file `fontconfig/fontconfig.h`. As a result I looked in `/usr/local/includes` to find out there really is no `fontconfig.h`. I tried purging `fontconfig`, but the system won't let me and gives me the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs : Depends: emacs24 or
                  emacs24-lucid but it is not going to be installed or
                  emacs24-nox but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

My question is, how can I reinstall `fontconfig` properly together with all header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-file` will tell you (install it if you don't have it already):

```
$ apt-file search fontconfig/fontconfig.h
libfontconfig1-dev: /usr/include/fontconfig/fontconfig.h
```

So

```
apt-get --reinstall install libfontconfig1-dev
```

should restore `fontconfig/fontconfig.h`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my fontconfig.h error in my cocos2dx applications. I will do the same for other missing headers.